# Modifying existing loop when no instance of matched criteria is present

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've included the base code that currently runs to essentially pull out info for a specific product category based on a larger master listing (approx. 4000 lines by 36 columns).  Previously this was not an issue, as the only codes listed and pulled out to individual sheets, were all is use; over time though, some of the older assigned product numbers are being discontinued and no longer in use.  All I'm trying to do is modify the existing structure so that it first does a sweep through the master listing to verify whether or not any lines match the c.Value and d.Value - if there are no lines that meet the matching c.Value and d.Value criteria then it should just perform the action in the If statement inside the loop (ie. delete the old sheet, make a new one, and populate "G2" with a generic "item code not located" value); if any lines are found that meet the c and d.value criteria then it goes through the normal process.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Item()
    CreateDeptReport "Item"
End Sub


Sub CreateDeptReport(Item As String)

    Dim shtRpt As Excel.Worksheet, shtMaster As Excel.Worksheet, shtPrevious As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim LCopyToCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, x As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 8, 3, 7, 9, 10, 39, 19, 24, 25, 27, 29, 33, 34, 35)

    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CurrentMaster")
    Set shtPrevious = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PreviousMaster")
    Set c = shtMaster.Range("AI5")
    Set d = shtMaster.Range("H5")
    Set e = shtMaster.Range("X5")

    LCopyToRow = 11

    Do

        If c.Value = 2516 And d.Value = "37A" And Not e.Value = "T1" And Not e.Value = "T3" Then

            If shtRpt Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Item").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                On Error GoTo 0
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=shtPrevious
                Set shtRpt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtPrevious.Index + 1)
                shtRpt.Name = Item
                Range("G2").Value = "Item"
                Range("C3").Value = Date
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If

            LCopyToCol = 1

            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

            For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value

            LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

            Next x

            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
        Set e = e.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop Until IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, -1))

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Item").Rows("10:10").Delete

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If LastRow <> 0 Then
            Rows(LastRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Range("A9").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Comment: Greetings! What's the question?

Comment: So, currently it only deletes the old sheet and copies over each line from the master list when it find a line that matches the specified criteria.  I need to modify so that it checks all lines first to confirm whether or not there are any lines that meet the specified criteria and, if not, then it deletes the old sheet and creates a new sheet in its place.

Comment: Currently, if it goes through and does not find any line matching the specified criteria then it leaves the old sheet and old information.  I need to find a way so that (1) the old information is deleted, as it does now, and (2) the new sheet reflects that no entry was found based on the criteria entered.  No msgboxes because this is only one portion of a larger process that runs a larger data pull, and I don't want that larger process stopping to deal with a msgbox popup.

Comment: I see towards the end, you stopped stating the worksheet to use.  for example `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` needs the worksheet before `Cells()`, and `Rows.Count`. do that for all range objects

Comment: So, if you do that manually, is it like that you will use `ctrl+f` and search `c.value` and `d.value` on `Item` sheet. If there is no match, you will delete the sheet. is it correct?

Comment: Which columns would the values you're looking for be located in? Also, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish... if it finds any of the values you're looking for, what exactly do you want the code to do? Also - if it doesn't find any of the values, delete the sheet, make a new one, and put a statement in `G2` - correct?

Comment: c and d values are located in columns "AI" and "H" of the shtMaster, respectively.  The code works, as is, when the c and d value combination is found.  Your last question is correct - I need to modify so that, if the combination of c and d values is not found, then it just deletes the old sheet, makes a new one, and puts some statement on the new, blank sheet ("G2" is fine as an example).

Comment: I assume you only want this check done once, and not on every iteration of `c` (as you are doing right now)? Otherwise you're going to run into trouble when you suddenly have a workbook with some tens of thousands of worksheets... And what worksheet are you looking for `c.Value` and `d.Value` in? I am assuming it would be `shtRpt`, but you don't declare it, and the way you frame your question makes it sound like there might be several worksheets (or even workbooks) - and yet you don't iterate over any?

Comment: The check needs to be done only once initially. If no rows are found that meet the c and d.value criteria then old sheet gets deleted and new, blank template sheet replaces.  If any rows are found that match the c and d.Value criteria then it would move to the rest of the code to identify each row that matches and copy those rows over to the newly generated sheet (as it does now).  And the values are searched in shtMaster, which is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you always want a new Worksheet for the `Item`.
So create the new worksheet first, then run the routine to find and fill the new worksheet with the records from the Master worksheet and use a variable (`Dim blItmFound As Boolean`) to flag when any record is found and at the end if there where no records found then enter in the new worksheet at `G2` the generic string you want *(see `Rem Validate Records`)*.

Please note that I changed `"Item"` for the value of the Variable `Item` and also changed this line:

```
Loop Until IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, -1))
```

for this:

```
Loop Until c.Value = Empty
```

for more details see [IsEmpty Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227(v=office.15).aspx)

This is your code adjusted:

```
Sub CreateDeptReport(Item As String)
Dim shtRpt As Excel.Worksheet, shtMaster As Excel.Worksheet, shtPrevious As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim LCopyToCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim arrColsToCopy
Dim c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, x As Integer
Dim blItmFound As Boolean

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 8, 3, 7, 9, 10, 39, 19, 24, 25, 27, 29, 33, 34, 35)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CurrentMaster")
    Set shtPrevious = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PreviousMaster")
    Set c = shtMaster.Range("AI5")
    Set d = shtMaster.Range("H5")
    Set e = shtMaster.Range("X5")

    Rem Delete Item Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Item).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Rem Add New Item Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=shtPrevious
    Set shtRpt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtPrevious.Index + 1)
    shtRpt.Name = Item
    Range("G2").Value = Item
    Range("C3").Value = Date
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Rem Get Records from Master
    LCopyToRow = 11
    blItmFound = False
    Do
        If c.Value = 2516 _
            And d.Value = "37A" _
            And Not e.Value = "T1" _
            And Not e.Value = "T3" Then

            blItmFound = True
            LCopyToCol = 1
            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)
                shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value
                LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1
            Next x
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
        Set e = e.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop Until c.Value = Empty

    Rem Validate Records
    Select Case blItmFound
    Case True
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Item).Rows("10:10").Delete
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If LastRow <> 0 Then
            Rows(LastRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Case False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Item).Range("G2").Value = "Item: [" & Item & "] code not located"

    End Select

    Range("A9").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: A clean solution for what I was asking.  Not having any issues with adaptation into larger processes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've read, it sounds like you should just search for the values in their respective columns beforehand. This is also assuming that if one of those conditions is false, you'll enter your new code. So you could do something like:

```
Set cRange = shtMaster.Columns("AI:AI")
Set dRange = shtMaster.Columns("H:H")

If cRange.Find(2516) Is Nothing Or dRange.Find("37A") Is Nothing Then
    'do code when either one of these conditions is false

Else
    'both values are found in their respective columns
    'do existing code
```

EDIT:

```
Set rng = Range("AI:AI")

Set origCell = rng.Find(2516)
Set currCell = origCell

Do
    Set currCell = rng.FindNext(currCell)

    If shtMaster.Range("H" & currCell.Row).Value = "37A" Then
        boolMatchingPair = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop While currCell.Row <> origCell.Row

If boolMatchingPair = True
    'found match
Else
    'no match
```

Comment: It's not a search to verify whether they exist independently in the respective ranges.  Similar to above, it needs to go through each row to verify whether or not any row on the shtMaster meets the c and d value criteria - if there is no row containing the c and d value pair then the old destination worksheet needs to be deleted and replaced with an empty sheet of the same name.  If any row is found that meets the c and d value criteria then the old sheet should be removed and replaced with a new one and the matching rows are then copied over to the new destination sheet from shtMaster.

Comment: Ok my apologies, I misunderstood. What about something like this:

Comment: Am getting "invalid procedure call or argument" error at `Set currCell = rng.FindNext(currCell)`

Comment: Hmm strange, this code worked for me on a little sample I had created. Hopefully the overall logic makes sense though (ie. find each row with the 2516 value, and then check if the other column in the same row has the value "37A". Just loop this until you're back at your original cell)